# Cannot redeploy to staging after swap to production using Azure App Service

Tags: github, azure-web-app-service

I'm running into an issue with Azure App Service using deployment slots. I have two slots: one for staging and one for production.

Here's the problem: It seems like the GitHub deployment key/connection is tied to the actual instance and not the deployment slot. This means when I deploy to staging and then swap with production, I'm unable to redeploy to staging.

I've already tried a few things to remedy this, including checking the deployment settings and app configurations, but there does not seem to be anything about tying github credentials to slot vs instance. The issue persists, and I still cannot deploy to the staging instance (previous prod) after swapping.

I can disconnect and connect again, but that would work once, and break again after swapping.

The strange part? If I swap back, it works fine again. It's as though the GitHub connection is swapping along with the underlying instances.

Is there a way to tie the deployment key to the slot, and not the instance?

Anyone else encountered this or have a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When two slots are swapped, all instances of the source slot get their settings from the target slot applied[1](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/app-service/deploy-staging-slots.md). The deployment key and link for GitHub are also included. As a result, when you switch to production, the underlying instances and the GitHub connection are also switched. You can configure a connection string or app setting to adhere to a particular slot (not swapped) in order to link the deployment key to the slot.

Comment: To accomplish this, access the Configuration page for that slot, add or modify a setting, and then choose Deployment Slot Setting. By checking this box, you can inform App Service that the configuration cannot be changed.

Comment: @Sampath afaik, there isn't a setting that allows sticking GitHub deploy key to a slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I found a workaround by creating an additional 'temp' slot. Interestingly, the staging slot would always show a connection to GitHub even when it lacked the necessary credentials. Here's the step-by-step process I undertook:

1. I first created this 'temp' slot and linked it to the GitHub
   repository, which allowed this slot to have its own GitHub deploy
   key.
2. Next, I swapped this 'temp' slot with my original staging slot.
3. The result of this swap was that both the production and staging
   slots now had valid deployment keys, but the staging slot was the
   only one configured for deployment from GitHub.
4. I deleted the 'temp' slot as it was no longer
   required.

This process resulted in two visible deploy keys in my GitHub repository, corresponding to the production and staging slots. While this approach is essentially a workaround, it successfully addressed the issue, and both slots retained their deploy keys after the swap. Also, I'm not sure why this is even an issue in the first place.