# Azure App Insights showing two instances (sometimes more) after creating and hooking Log Analytics workspace

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I have two enviroments (staging and production) that have the same configuration. They basically have one Azure Web Apps and Azure App Insights.
I enabled the Azure App Insights on both enviromnets, and usually checked the Application Map blade, and there was always 1 instance on the backend component.

As I'm working on a cross-component metrics on the staging environment, I had to have the Log Analytics workspace created and hooked to the Azure App Insights. What I mean by hooked it's that on Application Insights on the Diagnostic setting, I selected all Category Logs and AllMetrics to Send to Log Analytics workspace. After that, on the App Insights blade Application Map, it began to show two instances (sometimes more), which it's wrong I believe, because I didn't scale the app.

I couldn't find any clue why this happened.
In my production enviroment where I didn't do the Log Analytics workspace procedure, it's still showing only one instance as it should be.
On the staging enviroment I checked the Web App instance Count property and it shows "Instance Count: 1" and I also checked on the App Plan it shows "App / Slot: 1/1" "Instance Count: 1".
Can anybody help?

Comment: Hope this  SO [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76651131/cannot-redeploy-to-staging-after-swap-to-production-using-azure-app-service?noredirect=1#comment135197966_76651131)